# Change Hidden Input With onFocus Between UserControls

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

This is probably embarrassingly easy, but I've having problems getting this to work.

On ResidentAddress.aspx, I have 2 user controls (AppName.ascx and NavButtons.ascx).  When a textbox in AppName.ascx has focus, I want to update a hidden input field on NavButtons.ascx with the value of "TRUE". In the codebehind page for NavButtons, I want to see what the value of this hidden input filed is.

This is what I have so far:

**NavButtons.ascx**

```
<input type="hidden" id="IpChangeFlag" name="ChangeFlag" runat="server" value="FALSE" />
```

**AppName.ascx**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"  onFocus="document.getElementsByName('ChangeFlag').value='TRUE';">
```

**NavButtons.ascx.vb**

```
If IpChangeMade.Value.Trim.ToUpper = "TRUE" Then
    MyValue = true
End If
```

I am unable to change the value of ipChangeFlad. It always has the value of FALSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getElementsByName returns an array, access the first element.
`document.getElementsByName('ChangeFlag')[0].value='TRUE`'

Comment: I tried accessing the first element, like you recomended, but the value remained FALSE.  When debugging with firebug, I received the following error: "document.getElementsByName("ChangeFlag")[0] is undefined"

Comment: Finally noticed that the name value was being changed, so I removed the `runat="server"` from the input type and used the following to pull the input value: `Dim ChangesMade As Boolean = CBool(String.Format("{0}", Request.Form("ChangeFlag")))`